# django form field validation and error display

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to make a signup page just like:

[image]

When user click signup, I want to check the if the two password are the same, when not, give a error message after "confirm password".  Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CahrField(
        label=_("username"),
        max_length=30,
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(label=_('email'),)
    password_1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
    password_2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("password_confirmed"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    def clean_password_2(self):
        password_1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password_1")
        password_2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password_2")
        if password_1 and password_2 and password_1 != password_2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('password confirm failed'))
        return password_2
```

signup.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:signup_post' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {% for field in form %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
            <td>{{ field.errors }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <input type='submit' id="submit" value={% trans "signup" %}>
    <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">{% trans "Already have accounts?" %}</a>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def signup_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = forms.SignupForm(request.POST)

        if signup_form.is_valid():
            signup_info = signup_form.cleaned_data
            username = signup_info['username']
            email = signup_info['email']
            password = signup_info['password_1']
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password)
            user.save()
            # redirect to main page(not written so far)
        else:
            # I guess something wrong here, but no idea how to fix it.
            return redirect(reverse("accounts:signup"))

    else:
        signup_form = forms.SignupForm()

    return render(reverse("accounts:signup"), {'form': signup_form})
```

Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks!

Comment: @rajasimon password_1 comes from forms.SignupForm(request.POST), having nothing to do what clean_password_2 return.

Comment: @rajasimon when the two password aren't same, no error message display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should drop the first `else` clause altogether. If the form is not valid, you should not redirect, but fall through to the final `render` call which redisplays the form along with the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirect call doesn't display the errors because it has lost it's context. It should be enough to not redirect but instead print the error for logging purposes.

Instead of:

```
return redirect(reverse("accounts:signup"))
```

Try:

```
print "Invalid Registration Attempt: user:{0} email:{1}".format(username, email)
```

The errors will then be displayed when the form is present in the context upon rendering:

```
return render(reverse("accounts:signup"), {'form': signup_form})
```